# "targetEntity" from another bundle in Symfony2.3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I would like to use an entity in another bundle "targetEntity" property but it generated error...

Between this class :

```
namespace Tgb\CoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Website
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="core_website")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tgb\CoreBundle\Entity\WebsiteRepository")
 */
class Website
{

    /**
     * @var Tgb\BlogBunble\Entity\Blog
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tgb\BlogBunble\Entity\Blog", mappedBy="website")
     */
    private $blog;
```

And this one :

```
namespace Tgb\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Blog
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="blog")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Tgb\BlogBundle\Entity\BlogRepository")
 */
class Blog
{

    /**
     * @var Tgb\CoreBunble\Entity\Website
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tgb\CoreBunble\Entity\Website", inversedBy="blog", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     */
    private $website;
```

When I run line command :

```
sf doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I get :

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                
  The target-entity Tgb\BlogBunble\Entity\Blog cannot be found in 'Tgb\CoreBundle\Entity\Website#blog'.
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: ok only two first thoughts: have you cleared the cache? Bundles are both registered in AppKernel?

Comment: spelling mistake: BlogBunble -> BlogBundle

Comment: try this   php app/console doctrine:mapping:info

If you don't find you'r bundle you need to register the missing bundle in AppKernel

Comment: check if  auto_mapping: true 
in the App/config.yml folder

Comment: Refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745924/the-target-entity-cannot-be-found-in-mappingexception

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mispelled bundle in a few places:

```
   /**
     * @var Tgb\BlogBunble\Entity\Blog
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tgb\BlogBunble\Entity\Blog", mappedBy="website")
     */
    private $blog;
```

...and here:

```
    /**
     * @var Tgb\CoreBunble\Entity\Website
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Tgb\CoreBunble\Entity\Website", inversedBy="blog", cascade={"persist", "merge"})
     */
    private $website;
```

Replace `BlogBunble` by `BlogBundle` and `CoreBunble` by `CoreBundle`